# How to get the length of textbox text when user typing

Tags: javascript, html

I have researched this issue a couple hours and nothing worked out for me...
This is what I have:

```
<input id="txtSignInVerificationCode" runat="server" type="text" class="verificationTextbox" onkeydown="func()" />
```

...

```
<script>
    function func() {
        if ($("#txtSignInVerificationCode").val().length == 6)
            alert("NICE");
    }
</script>
```

My goal is whenever the length of the text written in textbox reaches 6, the user will get an alert immidiatly (without blur).
Thanks!

Comment: Your code will work as expected; though the user will get an alert after the seventh keypress, as the index starts from `0`. Is the problem you're having just that it happens at the 7th input rather than the 6th? If so, just change the number to `5`.

Comment: Use onkeyup instead

Answer (score 0):

The thing is in programming we always start counting from 0. I've just changed the length to 5. That should work properly!

```
<script>
        function func() {
            if ($("#txtSignInVerificationCode").val().length == 5)
                alert("NICE");
        }
</script>
```

***Edit:***

You can change the `onkeydown` method to `onkeyup` as well. In such case, no need to apply any of above changes.

Comment: finally, the solution for me was using
<script>
        

        function func() {
            if (document.getElementById("txtSignInVerificationCode").value.length == 6)
                document.getElementById("txtSignInVerificationCode").blur();
        }
    </script>

Comment: @Daniel proud of you!